# Export to CSV file using 'xlsx' in angular2

Tags: angular, csv, typescript, npm, xlsx

I want to export csv file using 'xlsx' npm module but in documentation it doesnt show any direct method for that. I have a json output and i want to export it using 'xlsx' module.Please help me for doing that. I tried this way but not working

```
const CSV_TYPE ='text/csv;charset=utf-8';
const CSV_EXTENSION = '.csv';
const worksheet: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(json);
const csvOutput: string = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_csv(worksheet);
FileSaver.saveAs(new Blob([buffer], {type: CSV_TYPE});, fileName + '_export_' + new Date().getTime() + CSV_EXTENSION);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: "Not working" how? What happens? Is there an error? Does it fail silently? Does exported file have wrong data? Does a dragon destroy your home planet?

Answer (score 3):

Your last line should be

```
FileSaver.saveAs(new Blob([csvOutput]), `${fileName}_export_${new Date().getTime()}${CSV_EXTENSION}`);
```

- You have to use 'csvOutput' to generate Blob.
- pass correct parameters to 'saveAs' function as described in [documentation](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/#syntax)

Fixed complete code:-

```
const CSV_TYPE ='text/csv;charset=utf-8';
const CSV_EXTENSION = '.csv';
const worksheet: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(json);
const csvOutput: string = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_csv(worksheet);
FileSaver.saveAs(new Blob([csvOutput]), `${fileName}_export_${new Date().getTime()}${CSV_EXTENSION}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using **FileSaver.saveAs()** method, so hope you are getting error related to **fs**.
try

```
 Xlsx.write(workbook,filename);
```